# Progress-bar with steps and arrow if there are more steps that are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a progress-bar that shows an arrow if there is more content still hidden. To make it more clear I made these:
Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

So I want to add the arrow in the after picture, I want it to hide again if I am at the end of the content.

My question is: Where do I start?

I have the progress bar:

```
 <div class="scrollmenu">
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <p class="divided">
                @foreach($survey['data']['formCategories'] as $key => $category)
                    <span><a class="progress-btn"
                             id="A{{$category['id']}}">
                            <span>{{$key + 1}}</span><br>
                        </a></span>
                    <span class="divider"></span>
                @endforeach
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But other then that I don't know where to start

The answer given by @Dan comes close but what I want is to lay the arrow over the content, not edit or add to the content.

Comment: Waaaay too much context missing. Please post your Javascript and HTML.

Comment: @mario_sunny I edited the question

Comment: What language is that loop written in? Is it PHP?

Comment: @NachoDawg Yes, I have php and Laravel in my project

Answer (score 2):

I did this before you edited the question, but if you want to go down the CSS-only route as your tags imply (you shouldn't, you'll have much more luck changing your foreach loop appropriately) then you could hide everything past the 5th element, and <strike>convert the 6th one to an arrow</strike> show a previously-hidden last element.

This pen is sloppy, but hopefully it gives you an idea of how to use the pseudoselectors.

```css
ul.progressblobs {
  display: table;
}
ul.progressblobs > li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.progressblobs > li.arrow, ul.progressblobs > li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
ul.progressblobs > li:nth-child(n+6) ~ li.arrow {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressblobs">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li class="arrow" role="presentation">&gt;</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: I've seen your comment about not wanting to edit the content. The problem is that the only real way to add something then is to alter the sixth element as I had previously posted. This is because you can't go "backward" in CSS; you can say "alter the fifth element" but can't say "but do this only if a sixth exists." Using pseudoselectors on the sixth element will then mean that any link on it will also become the link for the arrow.

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for but is there also a solution, lets say lay the arrow over the content, instead of changing the content in the li?

Comment: @SilkeNL I've edited the answer to a solution that doesn't involve editing the 6th element. The only reason I'd done that was because applying a pseudoelement to the 5th wouldn't let you use it as a link. This answer still isn't perfect, because it adds a non-semantic extra list item, but it's maybe closer to what you need.

Comment: But as I've said, I would look at your `foreach` loop instead...